# Running Firefox as root in a regular user's session is not supported

Tags: 20.04, firefox, selenium

**My system:**

- Ubuntu 20.04 (AWS)
- Python 3.8.5
- Geckodriver 0.28.0
- Mozilla Firefox 85.0.1
  Using arsenic library instead of usual selenium.

**Error:**  mozrunner::runner   INFO    Running command: "/usr/bin/firefox" "--marionette" "-foreground" "-no-remote" "-profile" "/tmp/rust_mozprofilerkumBD"

**Running Firefox as root in a regular user's session is not supported.  ($HOME is /home/ubuntu which is owned by ubuntu.)**

response body={"capabilities": {"alwaysMatch": {"browserName": "firefox"}}} data={'value': {'error': 'unknown error', 'message': 'Process unexpectedly closed with status 1', 'stacktrace': ''}}

Code:

```
async def arsenic_scraper(url):
    service = services.Geckodriver()
    browser = browsers.Firefox(**{'moz:firefoxOptions': {'args': ['-headless']}})
    async with get_session(service, browser) as session:
        await session.get(url)
```

My current Firefox permissions:

```
ubuntu@ $ ls -l /usr/bin/firefox
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 25 Feb  5 11:54 /usr/bin/firefox -> ../lib/firefox/firefox.sh
```

Comment: You should ask about the actual problem that you face.  Running firefox as root is a bad, bad, bad idea.  Why do you think you need to run firefox as root?

Comment: I don't see a problem nor a question to answer. All perfect as it is. We using Ubuntu do not use root.

Comment: How should i use it? its running itself from python

Comment: Why do you run that code from root?

Comment: Its Python app running headless firefox browser for web srapping.

ubuntu@:$ ls -l /usr/bin/firefox
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 25 Feb  5 11:54 /usr/bin/firefox -> ../lib/firefox/firefox.sh

Comment: But why do you run this app from root? Can't it run from a regular user account?

Comment: i am using sudo supervisorctl to add process for running, and conf file has line environment=HOME="/home/ubuntu",USER="ubuntu"
I dont select root